# Create 12 multichannel image starting from single RBG pictures

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have 12, three channels, RGB pictures (.jpeg). I would like to merge them in a unique 12 channels image using python.

I tried the following code converting each picture in a numpy array. I successfully create a 3D array with 12 arrays on axes 2 but it seems that PIL does not support saving multichannel images:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Load the first image
path = 'test_img_0000_Ch1.jpeg'
img = Image.open(path)
arr = np.array(img.convert('L'))

for x in range(2, 13):
    path = '_test_img_0000_Ch{x}.jpeg'
    img = Image.open(path)
    array_stack = np.array(img.convert('L'))
    arr = np.dstack((arr, array_stack))

image = Image.fromarray(arr)
image.save("multichannel.jpeg")
```

Comment: JPEG supports either 3 channels (when saving YCbCr) or 4 channels (when saving CMYK.) It doesn't support 12 channel images. I think .tiff supports an arbitrary number of channels, but then you have the problem that no other software will open it because there's no clear way to interpret a 12 channel image. But if you're going to produce a file that no other software can open... why bother making it an image at all? Save a .npy file; it's way less hassle.

Comment: You could fall back on tiff format. `tifffile.imsave` to save an image (assuming you imported tifffile).  Or dicom, depending on what those channels mean, or npz indeed, if that is some proprietary meaning that no software would ever understand anyway

Comment: Also, while we are at it, and whatever the way you use to save your image, never use `stack` (or `*stack`) in a loop. That means rebuilding a new array at each stage, copying from the last, etc. You may use python list (`array_stack=[]`; `array_stack.append(array)`), and then convert to a numpy array at the end. Or, even better, if you know in advance the size of the final array (which is the case in your example), create an empy `array_stack` with the correct shape (`(12,)+array.shape` I assume), and then store each array in its plane `array_stack[x-1]=array`

Comment: All that (including your initial code. In fact, your initial code even need twice more memory) implies that everything fits in memory. If it is 12 regular sized image, that is quite easy. But tifffile can also handle planes one by one, without having to have a huge `(num_planes, H, W)` block in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a *"multi-page"* TIFF with 12 images, each 640px wide and 480px tall like this:

```
from tifffile import imwrite
import numpy as np

# Create stack of 12 images, each 640x480 pixels
data = np.zeros((12,480,640), np.uint8)

# Make first image fully black, 2nd image grey(20), 3rd image grey(40)
for i in range(12):
    data[i, :, :] = 20 * i

# Save as 12 image multi-page TIFF
imwrite('result.tif', data, photometric='minisblack')
```

If you now open it in macOS **Preview** image viewer, you will see the single TIFF file contains 12 images, each one successively lighter than the previous one:

[image]

And if you check its content with **ImageMagick**, you will find 12 individual images within the singe TIFF:

```
identify result.tif

result.tif[0] TIFF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 3.51761MiB 0.000u 0:00.000
result.tif[1] TIFF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 0.000u 0:00.000
result.tif[2] TIFF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 0.000u 0:00.000
result.tif[3] TIFF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 0.000u 0:00.000
result.tif[4] TIFF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 0.000u 0:00.000
result.tif[5] TIFF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 0.000u 0:00.000
result.tif[6] TIFF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 0.000u 0:00.000
result.tif[7] TIFF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 0.000u 0:00.000
result.tif[8] TIFF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 0.000u 0:00.000
result.tif[9] TIFF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 0.000u 0:00.000
result.tif[10] TIFF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 0.000u 0:00.000
result.tif[11] TIFF 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit Grayscale Gray 0.000u 0:00.000
```

---

If you now want to read it back in, and take channels 0, 6 and 11 as R, G and B:

```
from tifffile import imread
from PIL import Image

im = imread('result.tif')
# Take channels 0, 6 and 11 as R, G and B
rgb = np.dstack((im[0], im[6], im[11]))
Image.fromarray(rgb).save('result.jpg')
```

The red channel is zero, the green channel is 120 and the blue channel is 220, so the result is largely blueish.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create an image with up to 32 channels, where 22 of these are meta channels in Imagemagick 7.  That is adding more channels after RGBA, the rest go into meta channels. These can be seen as extra channels (labeled as Alpha1-AlphaN) in Photoshop.

Here is an example adding grayscale or individual channels from 3 image into an existing RGB image.

```
magick lena.png \
\( mandril3.jpg -colorspace gray \) -channel-fx '| gray=>meta' \
\( zelda1.jpg -channel R -separate \) -channel-fx '| gray=>meta1' \
\( peppers.png -channel B -separate \) -channel-fx '| gray=>meta2' \
meta.tif

magick identify -verbose meta.tif
Image:
  Filename: meta.tif
  Permissions: rw-r--r--
  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
  Mime type: image/tiff
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 256x256+0+0
  Units: PixelsPerInch
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Type: TrueColor
  Base type: ColorSeparation
  Endianness: LSB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channels: 6.3
  Channel depth:
    Red: 8-bit
    Green: 8-bit
    Blue: 8-bit
    Meta channel[0]: 1-bit <------
    Meta channel[1]: 1-bit <------
    Meta channel[2]: 1-bit <------
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 65536
    Red:
      min: 53  (0.207843)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 180.23 (0.706786)
      median: 196 (0.768627)
      standard deviation: 48.8793 (0.191684)
      kurtosis: -0.792362
      skewness: -0.695346
      entropy: 0.947403
    Green:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 253 (0.992157)
      mean: 99.0252 (0.388334)
      median: 97 (0.380392)
      standard deviation: 52.5374 (0.206029)
      kurtosis: -0.738533
      skewness: 0.231172
      entropy: 0.961838
    Blue:
      min: 43  (0.168627)
      max: 216 (0.847059)
      mean: 105.384 (0.413273)
      median: 101 (0.396078)
      standard deviation: 33.4045 (0.130998)
      kurtosis: -0.141787
      skewness: 0.682631
      entropy: 0.932753
    Meta channel[0]:
      min: inf  (2.7431e+303)
      max: -inf (-2.7431e+303)
      mean: 0 (0)
      median: 128 (0.501961)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: 0
      skewness: 0
      entropy: -4.11713e+17
    Meta channel[1]:
      min: inf  (2.7431e+303)
      max: -inf (-2.7431e+303)
      mean: 0 (0)
      median: 173 (0.678431)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: 0
      skewness: 0
      entropy: -3.96554e+17
    Meta channel[2]:
      min: inf  (2.7431e+303)
      max: -inf (-2.7431e+303)
      mean: 0 (0)
      median: 44 (0.172549)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: 0
      skewness: 0
      entropy: -4.05002e+17
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0  (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 122.112 (0.478871)
      median: 65.6667 (0.257516)
      standard deviation: 43.2365 (0.169555)
      kurtosis: 0.938531
      skewness: 0.211794
      entropy: 0.473666
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33,0.03)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6,0.1)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06,0.79)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329,0.3583)
  Matte color: grey74
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 256x256+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: None
  Orientation: TopLeft
  Properties:
    date:create: 2024-02-11T17:41:32+00:00
    date:modify: 2024-02-11T17:41:32+00:00
    date:timestamp: 2024-02-11T17:41:32+00:00
    signature: 648e74bda0d28675626ed2dfe2645dd1d64f12aadb9a786ba249c348dc82f44c
    tiff:alpha: unspecified
    tiff:endian: lsb
    tiff:photometric: RGB
    tiff:rows-per-strip: 5
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 393504B
  Number pixels: 65536
  Pixel cache type: Memory
  Pixels per second: 13.0276MP
  Time-to-live: 0:0:0:0  2024-02-11T17:41:32Z
  User time: 0.000u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.005
  Version: ImageMagick 7.1.1-27 Q16-HDRI aarch64 21931 https://imagemagick.org
```

[image]

*(You can enable up to 64 channels by adding the --enable-64bit-channel-masks option to the Imagemagick configure build script)*

Answer (score 0):

As another option, [pyvips](https://github.com/libvips/pyvips) supports any number of images channels (also called "bands"). For example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import pyvips

images = [pyvips.Image.new_from_file(filename, access="sequential")
          for filename in sys.argv[2:]]
multichannel = images[0].bandjoin(images[1:])
multichannel.write_to_file(sys.argv[1])
```

I can run it with:

```
$ ./bandjoin.py x.tif ~/pics/x/*
```

`tiffinfo` shows:

```
$ tiffinfo x.tif
=== TIFF directory 0 ===
TIFF Directory at offset 0xbcfa1808 (3170506760)
  Image Width: 16382 Image Length: 4032
  Resolution: 72, 72 pixels/inch
  Bits/Sample: 8
  Sample Format: unsigned integer
  Compression Scheme: None
  Photometric Interpretation: RGB color
  Extra Samples: 45<unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha, unassoc-alpha>
  Orientation: row 0 top, col 0 lhs
  Samples/Pixel: 30
  Rows/Strip: 128
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
```

It's been saved as an RGB image with 27 (!!!) extra unassociated alpha channels.

JPEG2000 and VIPS also support multichannel data, although multichannel TIFF is more likely to be compatible with other software.